# Download multiple file types/extensions using WinSCP get command

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I'm calling WinSCP from a batch file and using the `get` command.

I want to download multiple files from a remote server with different file extensions and rename with timestamp on the local server.

As per the [WinSCP `get` help](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) I tried using this syntax, but it does not work for me

```
"get /remote/*.XLSX *.PDF *.TXT \\local\*_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%%.*"
```

But having multiple get commands does

```
"get /remote/*.XLSX \\local\*_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%%.*"
"get /remote/*.PDF \\local\*_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%%.*"
"get /remote/*.TXT \\local\*_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%%.*"
```

It's not a big issue, but I wanted to confirm that this is only way to make it to work with timestamp in a simple batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [multiple source parameters in the `get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#remarks). But they all need to be independent. So in your case, with a full path:

```
"get /remote/*.XLSX /remote/*.PDF /remote/*.TXT \\local\*_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%%.*"
```

You can make it shorter, by changing remote working directory first:

```
"cd /remote" "get *.XLSX *.PDF *.TXT \\local\*_%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmddhhnnss%%.*"
```